# BIO_set_fp() crashes on Windows

Tags: c, openssl, openssl-engine

I have the following OpenSSL code:

```
BIO* out = BIO_new(BIO_s_file()); // BIO_new_fp(stdout, BIO_NOCLOSE);
if (out == NULL) {
    CNGerr(CNG_F_CNG_CTRL, CNG_R_FILE_OPEN_ERROR);
    return 0;
}
BIO_set_fp(out, stdout, BIO_NOCLOSE); // Program exits with code 0x1 here
```

On the line `BIO_set_fp(out, stdout, BIO_NOCLOSE);` the program exists with error 0x1.

I am using Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by changing the flag in:

`Properties > C/C++ > Code Generation > Runtime Library: Multi-threaded DLL /MD`